# How to use rxrepl properly? My regex codes are not working

Tags: regex

I need to apply several changes to several text files using regex. I usually use Notepad++, but command line tools are better and faster than GUI solutions, so I discovered [rxrepl](https://sites.google.com/site/regexreplace/) yesterday and decided to use it. The help file of this software is quite succinct, but it says that it uses "Perl compatible regular expressions". If I remember correctly, Notepad++ is also Perl compatible, so the syntax I use in Notepad++ should work well in rxrepl as well.

Let's take an example. I have this:

```
{Blablabla}
"This is it"
```

And I want to convert it to this:

```
{YELLOW}{Blablabla}{WHITE}
"This is it"
```

A simple regex does the trick in Notepad++:

```
Search: (\{[^\}]+?\})(?=\r\n)
Replace: {YELLOW}\1{WHITE}
```

Now let's do this with rxrepl:

```
rxrepl -e utf8 --output-encoding utf8 --no-bom -c --no-backup -f test.txt -s (\{[^\}]+?\})(?=\r\n) -r {YELLOW}\1{WHITE}
```

I execute it and nothing happens. Obviously I'm doing something wrong but don't know where or when. By the way, if you know another free software to do this please let me know, maybe rxrepl it's not the best solution for this.

Regards!

Comment: Try `\{[^}]+}(?=\R)` and replace with `{YELLOW}$0{WHITE}`

Comment: Same problem, works well in Notepad++ but not in rxrepl.

Answer (score -1):

Wait a minute, I think I know how to solve this. The regex codes must be enclosed by "...". So simple, so easy, and the help file does not say anything about it.